# Merge CodeIgniter form validation rules

Tags: codeigniter, validation, merge

I've just started a little page using CodeIgniter and wanted to run CodeIgniter's form validation magic tricks. For this, I've set some rules via `config/form_validation.php`:

```
$config = array(
    array(
        'field'   => 'name',
        'label'   => 'Name',
        'rules'   => 'trim|required|max_length[64]'
    )
);
```

But in addition to that, I wanted to set some specific rules inside the controller itself.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', ' is_unique[table.name]');
```

My problem - the specific `set_rules()` seems to have reset all previously defined rules.

Is there a way to merge both set of rules? Or did I miss a method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to defined named array in the config file for each controller and use it as mentioned in the Codeginiter user guide.

```
$config = array(
             'signup' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'username',
                                        'label' => 'Username',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'password',
                                        'label' => 'Password',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'passconf',
                                        'label' => 'PasswordConfirmation',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'email',
                                        'label' => 'Email',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )
                                ),
             'email' => array(
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'emailaddress',
                                        'label' => 'EmailAddress',
                                        'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'name',
                                        'label' => 'Name',
                                        'rules' => 'required|alpha'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'title',
                                        'label' => 'Title',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     ),
                                array(
                                        'field' => 'message',
                                        'label' => 'MessageBody',
                                        'rules' => 'required'
                                     )
                                )                          
           );
```

Call it like $this->form_validation->run('signup') with the name of the array.

Comment: Ye, i thought of this solution after i've asked my question. It should solve my problem but the reason why i wanted to specify an additional rule at each controller is because pretty much every named array within this config would look the same except this one is_unique statement :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this exact issue before - where I wanted to use one set of rules, but add one extra rule for a specific controller.

Unfortunately you are correct - and the form_validation will overwrite the old rules. You cant even call the variable containing the old rules from the config - because its not stored in an accessible format.

The way I did the workout was to define the rules in a generic config file as arrays - and load the arrays inside the controller, then append a new rule, then set the whole array as the ruleset.

The other option is to just define two different rulesets inside the config file (even though they might be almost identical) - and just call the different rulesets as required.

Comment: This is the exact issue i have been facing but just for an additional rule i have to create a new group which seems weird but i think that is the only way to go i even tried to merge two groups and access with no success  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789238/can-i-use-validation-rules-in-ci-on-the-same-element-twice/

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have a lot of experience with CI however, as far as I know you should be able to append additional rules. Failing that consider trying:

```
$config[] = array('name', 'Name', ' is_unique[erfolge.name]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($config);
```

or use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) if you don't want to modify your standard configuration.