# Can i Use validation rules in CI on the same element twice

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I Have Defined my all rules in a form_validation file in config file

```
e.x

$config = array(
     'basic' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'alpha'
        ),
         array(
            'field' => 'age',
            'label' => 'Age',
            'rules' => 'alpha'
        ),
          array(
            'field' => 'city',
            'label' => 'City',
            'rules' => 'alpha'
        )

     ),

      'mandate' => array(
         array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
         array(
            'field' => 'age',
            'label' => 'Age',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),
         array(
            'field' => 'city',
            'label' => 'City',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ),

    ),
);


 $config["submitfinal"] = array_merge($config['basic'], $config['mandate']);
```

What i have been trying to achieve is there are two buttons in which one button is called (savenow) where when the user presses it, it should validate only for nonempty data and the other button is (save and complete) when the user presses it ,it should validate for non empty as well as other rule sets , so i had two groups defined separately and called them for (savenow feature) and when i try to combine both the groups the validation of basic group seems to be not working

Note: I Have applied validation on the same fieldnames in both the groups can you suggest me like how to go further on implementing save and complete feature.

Answer (score 1):

keep them seperate mean no need to merge them, just update mandate array as

```
'mandate' => array(
         array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
        ),
         array(
            'field' => 'age',
            'label' => 'Age',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
        ),
         array(
            'field' => 'city',
            'label' => 'City',
            'rules' => 'required|alpha'
        ),

    ),
```

then just call one specific group on click function.

Comment: The problem is i need to apply the rule=required|Alpha only on the  (submit) button, whereas i need rule=alpha on (savenow) button which enables validation if the content the user typed is wrong so as i have  it in two groups (rules apllied on the same field) instead of recreating a new group with rule=required|alpha i merged the two groups into one and tried to validate . So i wanted to know whether i can apply the rule on the same field in two groups and if so how it can be done

Comment: you can check in controller function that which button is clicked by checking posted array with name and then apply specific rule on the base of button clicked. that will be better for u i think so.

Comment: The Problem i Had was Merging rules(column value) if field names are same , i actually found the solution, the solution was to override the set_rules function in my extending class and checking if the field already exist appended it with a Pipeline | operator.